# Get HREF property

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<a class="some" id="1" href="/s/1/2">link 1</a>
<a class="some" id="2" href="/s/2/3">link 1</a>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.some').click(function() {
        var id = this.id;
        var link = $(this).css('href');
        alert(id);
        alert(link);
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

When I click on the link I get correct id, but "undefined" link.  What is the problem and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
var link = $(this).css('href');
```

to

```
var link = $(this).attr('href');
```

`.css()` is used to get/set CSS properties, `.attr()` is used to get/set attributes on elements.

Answer (score 1):

You need to access the elements attribute, not CSS property :-)

```
var link = $(this).attr('href');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

```
var link = $(this).attr('href');
```

Or simply:

```
var link = this.href;
```

Your code should look like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.some').click(function() {
        var id = this.id;
        var link = this.href;
        alert(id);
        alert(link);
        return false;
    });
});
```